# AWS SNS : Why is my "ghost" subscription not showing in Topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns, aws-php-sdk

I'm having a weird issue with Amazon AWS SNS : When creating subscriptions and topics using `aws-php-sdk` (3.112.7), there is always a "ghost" or "invisible" subscription.

[image: AWS Console screenshot]

As you can see, this **subscription exists in "subscriptions" tab**. However, when I click on the topic link (here `cav_56826`), **I can't see any subscription**.

[image: AWS Topic screenshot]

Do you guys already had a similar issue ? How can this happen ?

**Here is a my simplified code :**

```
  try
    {
        $arn = "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:app/APNS_VOIP_SANDBOX/ios_cav";
        $topics = array("allUsers", "cav_56826");
        $topicsToSubcribe = array();

        foreach ($topics as $topic)
        {
            $res = $this->snsClient->createTopic(['Name' => $topic]);
            if ($res->get('@metadata')['statusCode'] == 200)
            {
                array_push($topicsToSubcribe, $res->get('TopicArn'));
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("An error occured during Amazon SNS createTopic", $res->get('@metadata')['statusCode']);
            }
        }

        $SNSEndPointData = $this->snsClient->createPlatformEndpoint([
            'PlatformApplicationArn' => $arn,
            'Token'                  => $token
        ]);

        foreach ($topicsToSubcribe as $topic)
        {
            $this->snsClient->subscribe([
                'Protocol' => "application",
                'Endpoint' => $SNSEndPointData->get('EndpointArn'),
                'TopicArn' => $topic
            ]);
        }
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
       // Logs some errors
    }
```

Comment: Also, when delete a topic, create it again and make subscriptions, none of them seems to be added. But SNS sends me a 200 without any error

Comment: can you provide the version of the `aws-php-sdk` you are using, thanks.

Comment: The 3.112.7 ! :)

Comment: It seems that there is a kind of caching system, it's really weird

Comment: caching of what? did you create something before this issue happened?

Comment: also what php version you are using?

Comment: I’m using PHP 5.6.3

Comment: @mostafazh I'm just deleting a topic, create it again few seconds later, and then making new subscriptions.

Comment: if my answer has worked for you, please mark it as the correct answer i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png

Answer (score 2):

Using PHP `5.6.40` and AWS SDK PHP `3.122.0` (found [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/releases/tag/3.122.0)) and the below code after doing some changes, I can see the expected/right behavior is happening.

```
<?php

require '/usr/src/myapp/aws.phar';
$sdk = new Aws\Sdk([
    'region'   => 'us-east-1',
    'version'  => 'latest',
]);

$snsClient = $sdk->createSns();
$token = "XX:YY";

try
    {
        $arn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:360479286475:app/GCM/test-stackoverflow";
        $topics = array("allUsers", "cav_56826");
        $topicsToSubcribe = array();

        foreach ($topics as $topic)
        {
            $res = $snsClient->createTopic(['Name' => $topic]);
            if ($res->get('@metadata')['statusCode'] == 200)
            {
                array_push($topicsToSubcribe, $res->get('TopicArn'));
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("An error occured during Amazon SNS createTopic", $res->get('@metadata')['statusCode']);
            }
        }

        $SNSEndPointData = $snsClient->createPlatformEndpoint([
            'PlatformApplicationArn' => $arn,
            'Token'                  => $token
        ]);

        foreach ($topicsToSubcribe as $topic)
        {
            $snsClient->subscribe([
                'Protocol' => "application",
                'Endpoint' => $SNSEndPointData->get('EndpointArn'),
                'TopicArn' => $topic
            ]);
        }
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
       // Logs some errors
    } 

?>
```

all subscriptions:
[image: all subscriptions]

"allUsers" subscriptions:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. You have no problem ? Even if you quickly delete your topic and run code again ?